# How to find your scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you search your Google Drive for all your Google Apps scripts?

When I try to use the search options, scripts are not listed in the search type drop-down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding files with bound scripts associated (the script is embedded in the file) can be done by looking at your account's permissions.  This will list every file that has had some sort of permission request.  If a bound script does not require any permissions granted, I know of no way to finding the file.  To see the files you have granted permission to, use this link:
https://myaccount.google.com/permissions

If the scripts are not bound to a file, such as a Spreadsheet, then searching for `type:script` will give you a list of all stand alone script files.

Answer (score 2):

Search `type:script` in the Google Drive search bar.